# SQL foreach loop

Tags: sql

I'm very new at SQL scripts and couldn't figure out how to make a specific for each loop. I need to do something like this:

I have `Sites` and `SiteCrawls` tables.

Basically, for every site I need to create a new `SiteCrawl` and that `SiteCrawl`'s `Site_ID` column will equal to that site's ID.

How can I do this?

Comment: One word: **don't do it** with a foreach loop - SQL is **set-based** - you think and operate in **sets of data**. Using RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) like a foreach loop is very bad for performance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
insert SiteCrawl
(
    Site_ID
)
select
 s.Site_ID
from Site as s
where s.Site_ID not in (select Site_ID from SiteCrawl)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into site_crawl (site_id) values (select site_id from site);
```

So basically: there is no specific for/each in plain SQL, you handle tables and rows of results always as one statement.
So you could also say: there is no way an SQL Statement is something else than a for/each.
With that knowledge, you can see that the above query will insert one row into site_crawl for every site_id in the site table. You most likely want to use more values than this, but given the information from your question that is all I can do for you :)

Also: you want to read more about what sql is and how its used.

Have fun, SQL is a lot of fun!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Like I said, really new at sql and definitely ll work on it.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL you typically don't want to loop over every record.  It's very inefficient.

You could do something like

```
insert into SiteCrawl (Site_Id)
select Id from Sites
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into SiteCrawls (SiteID)
select SiteID 
  from Sites
```

Comment: Just had the same problem, that's helped.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg AFTER INSERT ON `Sites`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into SiteCrawls(Site_ID) values (NEW.id);
END
;
```

Comment: +1 thats most likely overkill for the given problem, but a nice solution.